# How do I using RedisMessageListenerContainer in configuration class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-redis

I am using spring-MVC and spring-data-redis to control Redis-cluster pool.
When I using jedisCluster.subscribe(new JedisPubSubListener(), "bb");

my application will stock in this code(I try to use thread but the other one can't get the instance in @autowerid).
I google a lot of way point me to using spring-boot .
but I can change the structure in our project.
So I think when spring init I can register a listener to use.
But I can run sauce in my original code.

Can someone make an example for me if I using this following code :

```
@Configuration
public class RedisClusterConfig {
    private List<String> redisNodes(){
        return Arrays.asList(redisNode.split(","));
    }

    @Bean
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig(){
        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdle);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWaitMillis);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnReturn(testOnReturn);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);        
        return jedisPoolConfig;
    }

@Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory redisClusterConnectionFactory(JedisPoolConfig 
jedisPoolConfig){
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new 
JedisConnectionFactory(new RedisClusterConfiguration(redisNodes()));
        redisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I setting in my configuration.

```
@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer() {

    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);

    container.addMessageListener(consumerRedis(),topic());
    return container;

}

@Bean
public ConsumerRedisListener consumerRedis() {
    return new ConsumerRedisListener();//this class implements MessageListener 
}

@Bean
public ChannelTopic topic() {
    return new ChannelTopic("channel");
}
```